Intuition about [8,3,2] code
Is there any intuition why this code would support logical CZ between any two logical qubits and transversal CCZ gate? What intrinsic property supports this? Can we possibly have a family of codes that has similar property?

The $[[8, 3, 2]]$ code is part of the $[[2^D, D, 2]]$ hypercube family, all of which share the property of strongly transversal CZ gates, and a weakly transversal CCZ. My intuition for these properties is (1) that the only X stabilizer is global and (2) the code is defined on a unit hypercube, i.e., it's only boundary and no bulk.

I'm not an expert on all this, and I'm sure there's lots of nice characterisations of when certain codes have certain implementations of gates, but there's a nice recent paper by Kissinger and van de Wetering about using phase gadgets to implement diagonal gates at any level $\ell$ of the Clifford hierarchy in a CSS code, essentially by checking whether certain strongly $\ell$-even matrices exist. They use the ZX-calculus throughout, which may or may not be your cup of tea, but either way the big theorem is ZX-calculus-free. There's quite a bit of terminology to define before it can be stated, however -- I tried drafting something here but it was pretty unclear and already very long! So maybe I'll just show your specific case, and you can check the paper for more details, or ask follow up questions.
CCZ gate
Turns out that the CCZ gate, which is at level 3 of the Clifford hierarchy, corresponds (up to Clifford correction) to the binary matrix
$$H = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^T $$
via some relationship to $\frac{2 \pi}{2^3}$ phase gadgets. We write the corresponding product of phase gadgets as $D_{3,H}$. And by the same relationship, applying $T$ to a set of 8 qubits corresponds to the $8 \times 8$ identity matrix $I$: i.e. $T^{\otimes 8} = D_{3,I}$. Next, it can be shown that an $[\![n, k, d]\!]$ CSS code with $r$ linearly independent $X$-stabilizers can be completely specified by an $n \times r$ matrix $S$ whose columns define the support of the $X$-stabilizers, and and $n \times k$ matrix $L$ whose columns define the support of the $X$-logicals. In your code's case, these are
$$ S = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^T $$
and
$$ L = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}^T $$
Now, the paper says that, up to Clifford correction, applying $D_{3,P}$ at the physical level applies $D_{3,H}^\dagger$ at the logical level iff the following block matrix is strongly 3-even:
$$ M = \begin{pmatrix} H & 0 \\ PL & PS \end{pmatrix} $$
You can check this is the case for $P = I$ (Example 4.3 in the paper!).
CZ gates
The same idea applies to logical $CZ$ gates. These are at level 2 of the Clifford hierarchy, so now we replace all the $\frac{2\pi}{2^3}$ phase gadgets above with $\frac{2\pi}{2^2}$ phase gadgets. The $CZ_{1,2}$ gate, for example, corresponds (up to Pauli correction) via phase gadgets to the matrix
$$ H = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
and applying $\sqrt{Z}$ to the final four qubits corresponds to the matrix
$$P = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 \end{pmatrix}$$
Matrices $S$ and $L$ are unchanged. The paper then says that (up to Pauli correction) applying $D_{2,P}$ at the physical level applies $D_{2,H}^\dagger$ at the logical level iff $M$ as defined above is strongly 2-even, which it is.

If you don't want any ZX calculus, you might also look at this paper: https://arxiv.org/abs/2303.15615

This blog post discusses the transversality of the CCZ gate for the [[8,3,2]] code and connections with standard properties for non-Clifford gates such as triorthogonality. The blog also comments on when 3D color codes can admit such CCZ gates in general, providing a partial answer to the OP's question of code families with similar properties.
https://earltcampbell.com/2016/09/26/the-smallest-interesting-colour-code/
